# Error when importing excel file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

My question maybe seems weird. I want to import excel file into SQL Server 2008 but when importing the file, i got an error "There was an error with input column "Address" on input "destination input". The column return status was " the value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data". I got the excel file from developer.

Comment: Is the 'Address' column in the excel workbook the same format at the 'Address' column in the SQL table? Are the strings in the 'Address' column in excel excessive?

Comment: Address format in excel is datetime & address format in SQL is nvarchar. That is why i cannot import into SQL. I cannot manually change the datatype in import wizard.

Comment: Are you importing into an existing table, or creating a new one? I'm pretty sure by default it suggests NVARCHAR(255) for text types, assuming you have more data than this in your excel worksheet could you change this to NVARCHAR(MAX)?